# memory-efficient web-browser

Tags: browser, memory

Any advice for a memory-efficient web-browser that runs under Windows XP? (And by memory-efficient, I mean one that uses the least *physical* memory. I'm running into limitations on my PC.)

Or are there ways to tweak settings on web browsers so they are more memory-efficient?

Opera seems pretty good, at least a lot better than Firefox or Safari.

**edit:** (just as a note, my particular application for this, is that I am trying to use a web application at the same time both as a user and as an admin. I can't login with both logins at the same time on the same browser because they use session cookies that clobber each other. So I'm looking for a lightweight browser to run the admin functions that come up occasionally while I am doing mostly user work.)

Comment: Google Chrome. I've not put this as an answer, because it's not a scientific answer.

Comment: ...maybe disabling Flash helps for *any* browser you're already using?

Comment: It's not the most memory efficient browser because each extra process has a memory penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera sounds very reasonable to me too. There are some tweaks and performance hints available on [this wiki](http://operawiki.info/OperaPerformance) page too.

See also [this](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2007/12/05/browser-memory-test-firefox-vs-ie7-vs-safari-vs-flock-vs-opera/) (old) comparison. Every addon and plugin needs memory, so if you get rid of flash, you can save much.

Comment: I found Opera to be CPU-intensive - not to the extent that Flash is in any browser, but I've kept away. Maybe your link warrants another look.

Answer (score 1):

Not scientific (/hat tip to Randolph's comment) but I'm having great luck with Google's Chrome on an old Pentium 2 ThinkPad with 288 MB RAM running XP.

My second favorite is [K-Meleon](http://kmeleon.sourceforge.net/) which is perhaps more light-weight, but not as fast with the JavaScript stuff which is where Chrome really shines on this old rig.

Comment: Thanks for the hat tip. I've not heard of K-Meleon so I think I'm going to check it out.

Comment: +1 for K-Meleon, However it is Gecko based browser, that one that powers Mozilla Firefox, however it is quite lightweight

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome). It seems to be very lightweight and minimalistic.

Comment: Google Chrome is anything but lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

[Arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) could be worth a look as it is designed to be lightweight. It's a webkit-based browser, so speedy at JavaScript work. Recently updated to include flashblock-a-like functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but maybe [Lynx](http://csant.info/lynx) is a good alternative. The [Lynx browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_browser) is basically a text-only browser so you can forget about flashy webpages and perhaps even visiting SO/SU/SF with it, but it's extremely lightweight, open-source and very geeky. :-) And because it won't display graphics, but just text, it also has a very small memory footprint.

However, I can't imagine there's still much interest in a text-only webbrowser these days...

Comment: I just tried browsing this site with lynx. Worked really well :-)  I didn't try to login though...

Comment: or links, which i hear does tables better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an [old version of Opera](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/win/), and turn off images, plugins, javascript etc (unless you need them).