# Best memory-efficient web browser for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, browser

I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 on an old laptop with only 756 MB of RAM, Pentium M 1.6 processor. I'm using Google Chrome 11.0 (dev channel) for web browsing, and it appears to be using up most of my memory and processor time.

Does anyone know of a better browser than Chrome on Ubuntu, for an older computer like mine? I'm new to Ubuntu, so there may also be tweaks I can make to my existing system to have it perform better. But right now it's pretty slow when I've got ~5-10 tabs open.

Related question:  [memory-efficient web-browser](https://superuser.com/questions/52824/memory-efficient-web-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different browsers, and different Ubuntu flavors, I finally found a solution that has worked well for me over the last ~6 months:  *Xubuntu* (or just the XFCE desktop environment with Ubuntu) and *Firefox*. With this, I haven't run out of memory (I've got 768M) or had any crashes. I tried Chrome, but it quickly eats up all my memory, and then my laptop starts thrashing, and then it becomes unusable. And since I was already running Ubuntu, it was easy to switch to Xubuntu.

The unstated assumption in my question is that I still want a fully-featured HTML5-supporting browser; some of the lightweight browsers in the Ubuntu Software Center would require me to give up some features.

Answer (score 2):

Going to the Ubuntu Software Center, searching for "web browser" or "lightweight browser", I found the following candidates:

midori, arora, netsurf, elinks, rekonq

(elinks is a text browser)